# $ f $ is continuous at any isolated points of $ E $. "Vacuously true"?

Tags: real-analysis

As $ p $ is isolated there exists $\delta > 0$ such that there are no points of $ x \in E $ such that 0 < |x-p| < \epsilon $

Then my note says "the inequality required is therefore vacuously true."

Does this mean that since there is no $ x \in E$ then the definition for continuity is always true? Since the assumption is always false?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p$ be an isolated point. Then by taking $\delta > 0 $ small enough, there are *no* points satysfying $0< |x-p| < \delta$. For such $\delta$, the implication

$$0< |x-p| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(p)| < \epsilon$$

automatically (or vacuously) holds, as there are *no* $x$'s witnessing the statement on the LHS of this implication.

Comment: Aha. Thanks you. That's very clear

Comment: That's a pleasure :)

Comment: Excuse me, may I ask a question? In the definition of continuity, it says $ |x-p| < \delta$ , not $0< |x-p| < \delta$. So can I change the proof a little bit like this way?: For such $\delta$, $p$ itself is the only point satisfying $|x-p| < \delta$. Then $|f(x) - f(p)| =0 < \epsilon$. Thus f is continuous at $p$.